# Debugging Android with Dalvik Debug Monitor

Tags: android, debugging, screenshot

I try to connect my HTC Android with my PC.

I also enable my debugging mode on my HTC.

When I try to run ddms.bat (Dalvik Debug Monitor), I can't find my mobile on that app. any way to fix it or any ideas?

PS: I want to take some screen shot of my mobile too.

Comment: Hi Grace here is a good link showing how to take the screen shots http://thetechnoclub.com/google-ocean/android-google-ocean/how-to-take-screenshots-in-android-phone/

Comment: Can you see your device in Device Manager?

Comment: @Egor, I can find my device in DM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enable USB Debugging. It can be done on the Setting->Applications->Development screen. After that, you have to install a driver for the ADB Interface. This driver is stored in <SDK>\google-usb_driver folder. If driver installation succeed you'll be able do find your device in DDMS Device list.

Comment: so funny.. it is working on my HOME Laptop and not working on my Office PC. I think I need some environment setup on my office PC.

Comment: Do you have your device in Device Manager? Is it working properly (is there an exclamation mark on its icon)?

Comment: it is now working. I forgot to install the USB driver. thanks. All I need is 1.J2SE JDK 2.Andriod SDK 3.Andriod USB Driver.

Comment: Glad you solved your problem. JDK is necessary for development, but it's an optional component when you just want to connect a device to a computer.